# How to access xts column by name in a function in R?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

How would I access an xts column by name in a function? The code below returns NULL.

```
#m(list=ls())
#dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"])
getSymbols("^GSPC",src="yahoo",from="2015-01-01",to = "2020-06-04")
str(GSPC)
frog<-function(ts,name) {
    ts$name
}
frog(GSPC,"GSPC.Close")
```

Comment: You can't use `df$col` with a string like that, use `df[[col]]` instead.

Comment: @Axeman : I think you are in a domain that you don't visit very often. `GSPC[["GSPC.Close"]]` returns `Error in GSPC[["GSPC.Close"]] : subscript out of bounds`. It's neither a data.frame nor a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quantmod provides `Cl` and `Ad` functions to extract the close and adjusted close.  See `?Cl` for these and other extraction functions.  For example, here are ways to get the close.  Note that in the second one the portion after the $ must be the column name and not a variable holding the column name.  Lists and data.frames work the same way with $ in R.

```
Cl(GSPC)
GSPC$GSPC.Close
GSPC[, "GSPC.Close"]
col <- "GSPC.Close"; GSPC[, col]
GSPC[, 4] # close is 4th column

frog <- function(x, col) if (is.function(col)) col(x) else x[, col]
frog(GSPC, Cl)
frog(GSPC, "GSPC.Close")
frog(GSPC, 4)
```

Comment: Cl(GSPC) gets me an: Error in has.Cl(x) : object 'GSPC' not found

Comment: forgot to get the symbols :) - that works well. thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `$` with string variables. For objects of type `xts`, you need to subset with the `[<row>,<col>]` syntax. So you need to do

```
frog <- function(ts,name) {
  ts[, name]
}
frog(GSPC,"GSPC.Close")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use pkg:quantmod, then you need to understand "xts"-classed objects which in turn inherit from the "zoo"-class when there is no xts-specific function defined:

```
#Your first lien of code should have been
> library(quantmod)

> class(GSPC)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

The data portion of such objects are accessed with matrix-like functions although they need to be specifically built in the package code:

```
> inherits(GSPC, "matrix")
[1] FALSE

# so not really a matrix but it has a matrix built into it:

> str(GSPC)
An xts object on 2015-01-02 / 2020-06-03 containing: 
  Data:    double [1364, 6]
  Columns: GSPC.Open, GSPC.High, GSPC.Low, GSPC.Close, GSPC.Volume ... with 1 more column
  Index:   Date [1364] (TZ: "UTC")
  xts Attributes:
    $ src    : chr "yahoo"
    $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-06-30 13:50:33"
```

If we remove its class labels it, like all zoo objects, is a matrix at its core.

```
str(unclass(GSPC))
 num [1:1364, 1:6] 2059 2054 2022 2006 2031 ...
 - attr(*, "index")= num [1:1364] 1.42e+09 1.42e+09 1.42e+09 1.42e+09 1.42e+09 ...
  ..- attr(*, "tzone")= chr "UTC"
  ..- attr(*, "tclass")= chr "Date"
 - attr(*, "src")= chr "yahoo"
 - attr(*, "updated")= POSIXct[1:1], format: "2023-06-30 13:52:43"
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:6] "GSPC.Open" "GSPC.High" "GSPC.Low" "GSPC.Close" ...

> inherits(unclass(GSPC), "matrix")
[1] TRUE
```

`GSPC[ , "GSPC.Close"]` should succeed

```
> GSPC[ , "GSPC.Close"]
           GSPC.Close
2015-01-02    2058.20
2015-01-05    2020.58
2015-01-06    2002.61
2015-01-07    2025.90
2015-01-08    2062.14
2015-01-09    2044.81
2015-01-12    2028.26
2015-01-13    2023.03
2015-01-14    2011.27
2015-01-15    1992.67
       ...           
2020-05-20    2971.61
2020-05-21    2948.51
2020-05-22    2955.45
2020-05-26    2991.77
2020-05-27    3036.13
2020-05-28    3029.73
2020-05-29    3044.31
2020-06-01    3055.73
2020-06-02    3080.82
2020-06-03    3122.87
>
```

Note that the `print.xts` function returns console output in a manner that resembles that of `print.data.table`

Comment: very informative. than you.